# Como puedo imprimir el constructor que se ha llamado?

Tags: java, poo, constructor

Quiero imprimir el tipo de constructor que se llamó por primera vez.

**Ejemplo:** si llamo desde el `main`.

```java
Carro carro = new Carro ("Toyota");
```

El resultado sea:

> "Llamaste al constructor de 1 parámetro"

Esto es lo que tengo por ahora:

```java
public Carro() {
        this("");


        if(contador == 2 || contador == 0)
            System.out.println("Llamaste al constructor de 0 parámetros");

    }

    public Carro(String nombre) {
        this(nombre, "");

        if(contador==1)
            System.out.println("Llamaste al constructor de 1 parámetro");
        contador+=1;
    }

    public Carro(String nombre, String matricula) {

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.matricula = matricula;

        if(contador==0)
            System.out.println("Llamaste al constructor de 2 parámetros");
        contador+=1;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En una clase tan simple como esta no me parece mal la respuesta de Riaven, pero en una clase con más variables y más lógica estarás repitiendo demasiado codigo, de ser necesario utilizar `this()` para evitar repetir código y iniciar todas las variables sin importar que constructor utilices, propongo esto..

```
public class Carro{

    private String  nombre;
    private String  matricula;
    private Color   color;
    private Motor   motor;
    private boolean isIlegal;

    public Carro() {
        this("","",0);
    }

    public Carro(String nombre) {
        this(nombre,"",1);
    }

    public Carro(String nombre, String matricula) {
        this(nombre,matricula,2);
    }

    private Carro(String nombre,String matricula,int parametros) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.matricula = matricula;

        motor = new Motor(4,120);
        color = new Color(1,0,0,1);

        if(matricula.isEmpty())
            isIlegal = true;
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        System.out.println("Llamaste el constructor de "+parametros+" parámetros");
    }
}
```

O crear un metodo para iniciar el objecto...

```
public class Carro{

    private String nombre;
    private String matricula;
    private Color color;
    private Motor motor;
    private boolean isIlegal;

    public Carro() {
        init("","",0);
    }

    public Carro(String nombre) {
        init(nombre,"",1);
    }

    public Carro(String nombre, String matricula) {
        init(nombre,matricula,2);
    }

    private void init(String nombre,String matricula,int parametros) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.matricula = matricula;

        motor = new Motor(4,120);
        color = new Color(1,0,0,1);

        if(matricula.isEmpty())
            isIlegal = true;
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        System.out.println("Llamaste el constructor de "+parametros+" parámetros");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

No hay necesidad de llamar a un contador, ya que al instanciar, al momento de entrar al constructor, pasará por todas las líneas de código que contenga este:

```java
    public class Carro {
        //atributos de Carro
        String nombre;
        String matricula;
        
        //Primer constructor, no recibe parámetros
        public Carro() {
            System.out.println("Llamaste al constructor de 0 parámetros");
        }
        //Segundo método constructor, recibe un parámetro
        public Carro(String nombre) {
            this.nombre =  nombre;
            System.out.println("Llamaste al constructor de 1 parámetro");
        }
        //Tercer método constructor, recibe dos parámetros
        public Carro(String nombre, String matricula) {
    
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.matricula = matricula;
            System.out.println("Llamaste al constructor de 2 parámetros");
        }
    
    }
```

Cada vez que cree un objeto ya sea por cualquiera de los tres métodos constructores, tendrá a la vez el mensaje correspondiente en la consola:

En tu `main`:

```java
         public static void main(String[] args) {
             Carro carro = new Carro();
             Carro carroUnParametro = new Carro("Toyota");
             Carro carroDosParametros = new Carro("Mazda", "SO-ES-19");
         }
```

Salida:

> Llamaste al constructor de 0 parámetros
>
> Llamaste al constructor de 1 parámetro
>
> Llamaste al constructor de 2 parámetros

Answer (score 4):

No tienes que realizar el llamado a `this()` ya que estarías llamando otro constructor. Tampoco necesitas de un contador, simplemente crea el constructor y define dentro la modificación de la propiedad que envías como argumento:

```
public class Carro {

 private String  nombre;
 private String  matricula;

     public Carro() {
        //this("");

       // if(contador == 2 || contador == 0)
            System.out.println("Llamaste al constructor de 0 parametros");

    }

    public Carro(String nombre) {
        //this(nombre, "");
        //if(contador==1)            
        //contador+=1;        
         this.nombre = nombre;
        System.out.println("Llamaste al contructor de 1 parametro");
    }

    public Carro(String nombre, String matricula) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.matricula = matricula;

        //if(contador==0)         
        //contador+=1;

         System.out.println("Llamaste al constructor de 2 parametros");
    }
}
```

De esta forma si instancias la clase puedes llamar el constructor apropiado, ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Carro carro = new Carro();
   carro = new Carro("Volkswagen");
   carro = new Carro("ŠKODA","SRX1212");
}
```

salida:

```
Llamaste al constructor de 0 parametros
Llamaste al contructor de 1 parametro
Llamaste al constructor de 2 parametros
```

Comment: que sucederia si la clase que tiene hiciera llamadas a los anteriores constructores? por ej, si llamas al constructor de `nombre-matricula`, este puede setear la matricula y llamar al constructor de `nombre` para setearlo y llamar al constructor sin parametros... Es una practica comun (incluso llamar al constructor parent). En ese caso te imprimiria todos los constructores por los que pasa, cosa que no es la pregunta.